# What's the C rating for NiMH batteries?

Tags: batteries

On most hobby Li-ion packs there is a prominently displayed C rating (typically 20 - 35), which tells you how many amps you can draw from it, in a multiple of the capacity.

I have never seen a C rating on a NiMH pack. Neither do you normally see how many amps you can draw from the battery.

What is a typical C rating for a NiMH battery?

Note: I am looking for an *estimate,* so if it's a range, go ahead and put that. I do not have a particular battery in mind.

EDIT:

I can see that I was misunderstood already by EM Fields. Let me try to clarify. The C rating refers to a constant with units of 1/hours which gives the peak amp draw in terms of the capacity, like this: Capacity [Ah] x C rating [1/h] = Max draw [A]

Comment: There is no "typical C rating for a NiMH battery". Your question(s) are based on faulty assumptions. It is not even clear that you even are using the proper definition for "C rating".

Comment: Read this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123709/panasonic-eneloop-bk-3mcc-4th-gen-where-i-can-find-maximum-discharge-current

Answer (score 0):

Capacity of a battery, or a cell, is given in ampere-hours and specifies how long current, at a specified rate, can be taken from a battery before the battery's  terminal voltage will decay to a specified value.

Check **[this](http://batteryuniversity.com/)** out.

Comment: I think the asker was looking for a number, not a definition.

Comment: I chose to teach him how to fish, since without a specific battery in mind, his question was unanswerable.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for at all. Capacity in Ah x **C rating in 1/h** = maximum continuous current in amps. I want to know what that C rating typically is.

Comment: @dpdt: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you have the formula in hand what's stopping you from getting the answer all by yourself?

Comment: The fact that there are two unknowns in the formula.

Comment: @EMFields I don't know what the C rating is for NiMH batteries. That is what I am asking. A range is OK (for example, for Li-ion batteries, it is usually between 20 for the cheap ones and 35 for really good ones).

Comment: @dpdt then look at the datasheet for the battery, it should give you some idea. If your battery doesn't have a datasheet, then you should ditch it and buy one that does.

Answer (score 0):

The "C" rating specifies the maximum safe continuous discharge rate of a pack. If you see 10C on your battery, it means it can be discharged at 10 times that pack's capacity.

This applies to all batteries. There is no difference between Li-ion and NiMH (or any other chemistry, for that matter).  If you are not seeing the capacity or "C" factor for batteries, then you are shopping in places where the vendor isn't giving you the full specifications.

Avoid buying from people who don't know what they are talking about, or who fail to reveal all the important specs, whether knowingly or ignorantly.

Ref: https://www.commonsenserc.com/page.php?page=c_ratings_explained.html